java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'localexpert.company_cities' doesn't exist where company and city are different tables
I've got "Table 'localexpert.company_cities' doesn't exist" exception, I tried to use "_" to separate company and city tables but it doesn't work. Here is my JPA repo and entities:
@Repository("VisitorCompanyListCompanyRepository")
interface VisitorCompanyListCompanyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<VisitorCompanyListCompanyEntity, Long> {

    Page<VisitorCompanyListCompanyEntity>
    findAllByCitiesCityAndServicesNameAndScopesScope(String city, String service,
                                                     int scope, Pageable pageable);
}

@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class VisitorCompanyListCompanyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String gallery;


    @ManyToMany
    private List<VisitorCompanyListCityEntity> cities;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<VisitorCompanyListScopeEntity> scopes;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<VisitorCompanyListServiceEntity> services;
}

@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class VisitorCompanyListCityEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "value")
    private String city;

}

It seems to me that JPA cannot recognise properly VisitorCompanyListCityEntity, but i don't know why. I just try to get companies filtered by city name.

JPA is looking for the table induced by the ManyToMany relationship, where is this table located ?

Okay, i forgot it is needed. Thanks a lot
